# Watch all sub directories with node-sass

Tags: npm, node-sass

I've seen many examples for watching a specific folder with `node-sass`, but my css isn't all in the same single folder.  I'd like to have it watch all subdirectories for scss files the way you can with `onchange` (just for example).  I'd assume that the syntax would be something like:

```
`node-sass -w app/**/*.scss -o app/**/`
```

...but that yields the error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'app/**/*.scss'`

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with `node-sass`?  If not, is there a better way to mass-compile my scss files to css?  I'm trying to stick to just npm scripts for my build if possible.

Answer (score 19):

Try `node-sass  -rw app -o app`.
You might want to change your output folder as this might keep looping.

Source:

> -r, --recursive            Recursively watch directories or files
>   https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Comment: the -rw watched and compiled any files included in my main.scss file. Perfect~~

Comment: @g3mini This gives me error on cmd: events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Any idea?

Comment: I wish I could help but after 2 years I stopped using node-sass :P

Comment: `-w, --watch Watch a directory or file`

Comment: at 2023 I have an old project in hands, this loop issue is still a problem  If someone has a fix feel free to share it lol

Answer (score 0):

For node-sass to recognise a newly created file, I found I needed to restart node-sass/npm.